# Unity GameObject.SetActive(true) is being funky

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i want to make an object pooling system for my game (and possibly future games) and well i pretty much got it figured out, except for a tiny detail which is frustrating the hell out of me.

In my SpawnFromPool method i Dequeue an object and SetActive(true);.
I then call Debug.Log(objToSpawn.activeSelf);
This logs True, but the object is not active in the scene.

Below you'' find the ObjectPooler class and the Spawner class i'm using. I'll also inclue a screenshot of my console.

Here's the entire ObjectPooler class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Library.ExtensionMethods; //Just use this to convert from enum to int like once i think...

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour 
{
    #region Singleton

    private static ObjectPooler _instance;

    public static ObjectPooler Instance { get { return _instance; } }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);
        _instance = this;
    }

    #endregion

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Pool
    {
        public GameObject Prefab;
        public int AmountToStartWith;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private List<Pool> _pools = new List<Pool>();

    private Dictionary<PoolTypes, Queue<GameObject>> _poolDictionary = new Dictionary<PoolTypes, Queue<GameObject>>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _pools.Count; i++)
        {
            RequestObjectsOnStart(
                i,
                _pools[i].Prefab,
                _pools[i].AmountToStartWith
                );
        }        
    }

    public GameObject SpawnFromPool(PoolTypes type, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        if (!_poolDictionary.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Pool with tag " + type + " doesn't exist!");
            return null;
        }

        if (_poolDictionary[type].Count == 0)
            AddToPool(type.ToInt(), _pools[System.Convert.ToInt32(type)].Prefab, 1);

        GameObject objToSpawn = _poolDictionary[type].Dequeue();
        objToSpawn.SetActive(true);
        objToSpawn.transform.position = position;
        objToSpawn.transform.rotation = rotation;

        Debug.Log(objToSpawn.activeSelf);
        Debug.Log(_poolDictionary[PoolTypes.Cube].Count);



        return objToSpawn;
    }

    public void RequestObjectsPerFrame(int type, GameObject obj, int amount)
    {
            StartCoroutine(AddToPoolPerFrame(type, obj, amount));
    }

    private void RequestObjectsOnStart(int type, GameObject obj, int amount)
    {        
        AddToPool(type, obj, amount);
    }

    private void AddToPool(int type, GameObject obj, int amount)
    {
        Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            GameObject newObj = Instantiate(obj);
            newObj.SetActive(false);
            objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
        }

        if (_poolDictionary.ContainsKey((PoolTypes)type))
        {
            foreach (GameObject pooledObj in objectPool)
            {
                _poolDictionary[(PoolTypes)type].Enqueue(pooledObj);
            }
            return;
        }

        _poolDictionary.Add((PoolTypes)type, objectPool);
    }

    private IEnumerator AddToPoolPerFrame(int type, GameObject obj, int amount)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            AddToPool(type, obj, 1);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the entire Spawner class

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour 
{
    ObjectPooler _op;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        _op = ObjectPooler.Instance;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject obj;
            obj = _op.SpawnFromPool(PoolTypes.Sphere, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The Extension Method i used in case someone was curious, or if that's where the problem is...

```
public static int ToInt<T>(this T e) where T : struct, System.IComparable
{
    if (!(typeof(T).IsEnum))
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Value must be an enum");
    return (int)(object)e;
}
```

This is what the looks like after i left click once. The important one is the one that says true baing called after the objectToSpawn.SetActive(true); in the SpawnFromPool method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the major problem:

```
objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
```

It should be

```
objectPool.Enqueue(newObj);
```

Your "obj" is just the prefab, and newObj is the instantiated object, which you should add into the pool.

```
 GameObject newObj = Instantiate(obj);
 newObj.SetActive(false);
 objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
```

Comment: Ofcourse it was a result of bad naming, i feel very stupid right now, but alas, i cannot dwell in the past. Thank you for debugging for me :) It works just fine now, and i renamed that variable too so it doesn't happen again xD

Comment: congratulation :)